# Using getText (Selenium) to retrieve the value of a radio button option

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I've been writing selenium automated tests for a few months now but have yet to really use GetText...however I really need to retrieve the name of a radial button option, using C# and NUnit with selenium...here is the line of html I am trying to retreive the value from (Bordelaise)

```
<input id="uc_OrderOptions_rptr_OrderOptions_ctl01_SelectedValue0_0" type="radio" name="uc_OrderOptions$rptr_OrderOptions$ctl01$SelectedValue0" value="Bordelaise" /><label for="uc_OrderOptions_rptr_OrderOptions_ctl01_SelectedValue0_0">Bordelaise</label>
```

I have tried getText(id above) and a few other things that haven't worked...anyone got an idea of what I could do?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get **name**, **value** or **text**?

You can do it with xPath and some Selenium methods.

**Name**:

```
getAttribute("//input[@id='uc_OrderOptions_rptr_OrderOptions_ctl01_SelectedValue0_0']@name");
```

**Value**:

```
getValue("//input[@id='uc_OrderOptions_rptr_OrderOptions_ctl01_SelectedValue0_0']");
```

**Text**:

```
getText(//input[@id='uc_OrderOptions_rptr_OrderOptions_ctl01_SelectedValue0_0']/label");
```

Comment: A bit of an update after trying the getText line above (with the " quotations that are missing of course)....selenium gives me an error saying the id was not located...color me confused. If Xpath requires an XML file to begin with and I'm dealing with html, can I convert the html file to xml? Excuse me if these are newbie questions...I'm relatively new to writing automated tests... thanks!

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'd imagine you received the error because your xpath operates under the assumption that the label tag is nested within the input tag.

That would make things much simpler, but it seems generally labels are self maintained and reference the input via their "for" var.

ie. 
<input type="radio" value="1" id="option_1" />
<label for="option_1"> Option #1 </label>